# How to get args passed to a function

Tags: python, introspection

Is there a way in python to get the arguments that were passed by the caller to a function? Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
# function
def repeat(self, min=None, max=None, optional=False):
    do_something()
```

I need to do something differently based upon whether one or more args were passed to it. For example:

```
r.repeat('hello').repeat(2,None)
```

Needs to be differentiated between:

```
r.repeat('hello').repeat(2) # only one arg passed
```

I thought `locals` might be a good place to start, but it picks up the default arg from the function so doesn't work for my purposes:

```
{'_max': None, '_min': 2, 'discrete': [], 'optional': False, 'max': None, 'min': 2, 'self': r'(hello)'}
```

In other words, `max` should not show up as one of the args. Is this possible to do in python? I've also tried using `inspect`, but that seems to show the defaults as well:

```
(Pdb) inspect.getargvalues(f)
ArgInfo(args=['self', 'min', 'max', 'optional', 'discrete'], varargs=None, keywords=None, locals={'pdb': <module 'pdb' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pdb.py'>,
 '_max': None, '_min': 2, 'discrete': [], 'optional': False, 'max': None, 'min': 2, 'self': r'(hello)', 'f': <frame object at 0x101e2de68>})
```

Comment: From what I understand, internally python does not keep track of what was a default argument and what was actually passed, so I don't think that `inspect` can help here since `None` is both a default and a valid input argument. Using a  [sentinel object](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/) for default instead of `None` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58667783/1399279) is the most common workaround I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are simpler solutions to your problem. The simplest way I know is to have a default value which could not possibly be passed in as an actual argument. Create a dummy object and use that as the default:

```py
dummy_default = object()

def my_function(x=dummy_default):
    actual_x = None if x is dummy_default else x
    # ...
```

This way, `actual_x` will be `None` either if no argument is passed, or `None` is passed explicitly, but you can distinguish between these cases by testing `x is dummy_default`.

---

You could also use `*vargs`:

```
def my_function(*vargs):
    if len(vargs) > 1:
        raise TypeError('Too many arguments')
    x = vargs[0] if len(vargs) >= 1 else None
    # ...
```

The expression `len(vargs) == 0` will tell you whether no argument was passed.

This way is a bit worse because making keyword-arguments work too is more complicated, you won't get a useful argument hint if you use an IDE, and you need to do your own error-handling for wrong numbers of arguments.

Comment: Agreed. Every time I had to do something like the OP wants to do I ended up having to use one of these two methods.